# NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type Expected NSMutableArray but found __NSDictionaryI:

Tags: ios, arrays, objective-c, swift, type-conversion

I'm trying to pass an `NSMutableArray` from an Objective-C ViewController to a Swift ViewController, the problem is that the Swift ViewController can't understand the `NSMutableArray` type and he gives me this error when i try to access the array in Swift i get this error:

> Precondition failed:
>
> NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type
>
> Expected NSMutableArray but found __NSDictionaryI

I tried multiple solutions like converting the `NSMutableArray` to a Swift String array with this following code :

```
var swiftArray = objCMutableArray as NSArray as! [String]
```

or this:

```
let swiftArray: [String] = mutableArray.flatMap { $0 as? String }
```

but it always gaves me this error:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryI' (0x1083bdcf8) to 'NSString'

Comment: you have a dictionary inside not a string, how do you want to pass that as string?

Comment: i just want the swift view controller to read the array

Comment: `as NSArray as! [String]` — why?

Comment: you need to know what you have in that array or even if it is an array before swift can read it like that

Comment: You have an Array of Dictionary ([NSDictionary]) not [String].

Comment: yes and i need to read it in swift

Comment: it's actually an NSMutableArray that countaints arrays of NSDictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution i found is when i pass the array i convert it to NSData so the swift can read it using the following code:

```
NSData *data1 = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.mSelectedBills];
```

and then in the swift ViewController i use this code to read it:

```
@objc func setSelectedBillsData(selectedBillsData: NSData) {
    self.mData = selectedBillsData
    do {
        if let loadedStrings = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: selectedBillsData as Data) as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
            print(loadedStrings)
        }
    } catch {
        print("erreur.")
    }
}
```

Comment: Why? It's not a viable solution.

Comment: that's the solution that i have found, if you have the alternative then go on

Comment: According to your previous code: `var swiftArray = objCMutableArray as NSArray as! [String]`=> `var swiftArray = objCMutableArray as! [[String:AnyObject]]`?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

```
if let swiftArray = objCMutableArray.mutableCopy() as? Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>> {

}
```

Comment: I have edited my answer. please check may be it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It should work

```
if let swiftArray = objCMutableArray as? [[String:AnyObject]]{
    print(swiftArray)
}
```

It was the type matching problem of the NSmutableArray elements when casting to the array of string. It should be array of dictionary.